# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'htmlMimeMail' not found in class not found error

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'htmlMimeMail' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\surat\includes\common.php:293 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\surat\index.php(10): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\surat\includes\common.php on line 293

This Error

I have configure my website in localhost I have php version is 7.4.

I have problem is class not found can please give me any suggestion

Thanx in advance

```
global $mail;
$mail = '';
$mail = new htmlMimeMail();

global $db;
global $db1;
global $db2;
global $dbtemp;

$db     = '';
$db1    = '';
$db2    = '';
$dbtemp = '';

$db     = new DB_Sql($config['DB_Host'], $config['DB_Name'], $config['DB_User'], $config['DB_Passwd'], false);
$db1    = new DB_Sql($config['DB_Host'], $config['DB_Name'], $config['DB_User'], $config['DB_Passwd'], false);
$db2    = new DB_Sql($config['DB_Host'], $config['DB_Name'], $config['DB_User'], $config['DB_Passwd'], false);

$dbtemp = new DB_Sql($config['DB_Host'], $config['DB_Name'], $config['DB_User'], $config['DB_Passwd'], false);

if(!$db->link_id())
{
  die("Could not connect to the database");
}
```

This above code is my common.php code
and i include common.php file in index.php as below

```
include_once("./includes/common.php");
```

Comment: You need to clear up your question and provide code samples otherwise you're unlikely to get help from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound ridiculous ... But do you actually include the library? As that would be about the only reason I can think off.

This is not necessary, unless you're in a function. Which you don't seem to be or you removed too much coding from your post.

```
global $mail;
```

Comment: thanx Paddy                                                                                                                                                            i have update my code please check.

Comment: $config is not defined. And you don't include the library for htmlMimeMail();.   Do you include this somewhere? Or something like that?  include('classes/htmlMimeMail.php');